# The mission is to turn each word's first letter into capital (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The code below doesn't work why?

```
function titleCase(str){
    var newStr = str.split(" "); //split string turn it into seperated words[]
    var resutl;

    for(vari=0; i < newStr.length; i++){ //iterate all words
        var result = newStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase + 

        // find first letter and turn it into capital 
        newStr[i].subString(1).toLowerCase(); 
    }
    return result.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: vari=0 space is missing, should be var i = 0, also correct spelling of variable 'result' and initialize it once outside loop

Comment: Question about debugging need to describe specifically what behavior you are seeing, and what you desire to see instead, not just a "This code doesn't work" message

Answer (score 0):

result in your code is a string, not an array. you cannot join a string.

each iteration of the loop you are replacing the variable result with a new word. you need to initialize a result array [] and push each result onto the array, then join the array after the loop has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string on spaces and iterate it with the function below:

```
function ucfirst(str) {
    str += ''; // make sure str is really a string
    var f = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    return f + str.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: what does `str += '';`  do?

Comment: cheesy way to make sure it is converted to a string :)

Answer (score 0):

The `result` needs to be an array and also you have some typos in your code, e.g. missing `()`

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    var newStr = str.split(" ");
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
        result.push(newStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newStr[i].substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
    return result.join(' ');
}


var str = 'hELLO wORLD';

document.write(titleCase(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
function titleCase(str){ 
 var newStr = str.split(" "); 

 var result = [];

 for(var i=0; i < newStr.length; i++){ 
   result.push(newStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
    newStr[i].substring(1).toLowerCase());

 } 

  return result.join(' ');

}
```

Another Approach:

```
function titleCase(str){ 
  var words = str.split(" ");

 return words.map(function(word){
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expression

```
var data = "The mission is to turn each word's first letter into capital"; 
data = data.replace(/ (.)/g,function(w){return w.toUpperCase()});
```

drawback :this will not capitalize the first character.